# ReferenceError: User is not defined sovle this problem

Tags: express

const user = require('../modules/User')  const express  = require('express')  const router = express.Router();   router.get('/',(req,res)=>{     console.log(req.body)     user =  User(req.body);       User.save();    res.send(req.body); }

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
name: {
type: String,
require: true,
},
email: {
type: String,
require: true,
unique: true,
},
password: {
type: String,
require: true,
},
date: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now,
},
});

module.export =  mongoose.model('user',UserSchema)

Comment: There a several issues with how you are defining your variables. Does `console.log(req.body)` print what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error simply means that the User is not defined.Because you are importing it as `const user = require('../modules/User');`.You should import it as  `const User = require('../modules/User');` and there are other issues as well in your code.

1. You should define the model name as `User` not `user` in mongoose.model() function , like `module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);`
2. One suggestion if you don't want to get stuck in these import typos.. Do consider using something like `module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);`
3. Creating an entry in a database is an async operation so you should use async await in your `router.get` handler .So it will be something like this

```js
const User = require('../modules/User');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        const user = await User(req.body);
        //Now you don't need to save the user it will be saved automatically
        //User.save();
        res.send(user);
    };
```